# How to access all nested associative array elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

**Situation :** I receive JSON array from jQuery <-> PHP Ajax request. Here's structure of unparsed JSON aray :

```
{"Focus":{"id":2,"brand":"Ford","name":"Focus"}}
```

And after using `JSON.parse(json);` the structure looks like :

```
    Focus: Object
       brand: "Ford"
       id: 2
       name: "Focus"
```

**Problem :** I want to access all array's '1st tier' elements and use them like an object, but none of the following ways works :

```
for (var entity in dataTable)
{
   formattedText += entity['brand'] + " " + entity['name'] + "<br>";
   OR
   formattedText += entity.brand + " " + entity.name + "<br>";
   OR
   formattedText += dataTable[0]['brand'] + " " + dataTable[0]['name'] + "<br>";
}
```

Any solutions how to read values of all object in this array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop uses *keys* and does not return the elements themself: `for (var key in dataTable)`
You would then access each element with `dataTable[key]`. The *key* is actually the name of the Element.

You where using it as you would use a [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop, but that is a new feature not supported in all Browsers yet.

Demo:

```js
var dataTable = {"Focus":{"id":2,"brand":"Ford","name":"Focus"}}

var formattedText = ""
for (var key in dataTable)
{
   formattedText += dataTable[key]['brand'] + " " + dataTable[key]['name'] + "<br>";
}

document.write(formattedText)
```

Answer (score 1):

> `Object.keys` will return array of all the keys of the `object`

You can loop([`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)/`for-loop`) through the `keys` to get the expected output.

Using `forEach`:

```js
var dataTable = {
  "Focus": {
    "id": 2,
    "brand": "Ford",
    "name": "Focus"
  }
}
var keys = Object.keys(dataTable);
var str = '';
keys.forEach(function(item) {
  str += dataTable[item].brand + " " + dataTable[item].name;
});
alert(str);
```

Using `for-loop`:

```js
var dataTable = {
  "Focus": {
    "id": 2,
    "brand": "Ford",
    "name": "Focus"
  }
}
var keys = Object.keys(dataTable);
var str = '';
for (var i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i++) {
  str += dataTable[keys[i]].brand + " " + dataTable[keys[i]].name;
}
alert(str);
```

Comment: Isn't it the same as the `for..in` loop, but slower and more complicated?

Comment: The test is using `hasOwnProperty` for each Element, that not nesessary

Comment: Yes! Not necessary but it is suggested to use it to make sure keys that are on that object instance. This is not the case with `Object.keys()`

Comment: Well you might want to use inherited Elements..(but this is a JSON-Like-Object, so who cares) then it would be about the same speed. But the `forEach` is realy slow, you would need a normal for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax to write this would be:

When you loop, you'll get the key name in the variable **entity** and then use that to get the value, also, you need to access the associative array inside the first key i.e. **Focus**

```
var dataTable = JSON.parse('{"Focus":{"id":2,"brand":"Ford","name":"Focus"}}');
var formattedText = '';
for (var entity in dataTable.Focus) {
    formattedText += dataTable.Focus['brand'] + " " + dataTable.Focus['name'] + "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're using each function in a wrong way. in your each function change arguments to key and value like this:

```
$.each(dataTable, function (key, value) {
     //access key and values here
});
```

In your case u should iterate again over key and values of your key values.